# SmtpClient кодировка в заголовке письма

Tags: c#, smtp

Отправляю письмо с сервера, вот таким вот методом:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// асинхронная отправка почты
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="to">кому, коллекция получателей</param>
    /// <param name="subject">тема</param>
    /// <param name="body">тело в html формате</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="SmtpException">различные варианты ответов на ошибки, сервером</exception>
    public async Task SendMessageAsync(IEnumerable<String> to, String subject, String body)
    {
        using (SmtpClient smtp_client = new SmtpClient(host: this.smtp_server, port: this.smtp_port))
        {
            smtp_client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName: this.login, password: this.password);
            smtp_client.EnableSsl = this.enable_ssl;
            using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
            {
                if (this.is_spam)
                {
                    message.Headers.Add(name: "Precedence", value: "bulk");
                    message.Headers.Add(name: "List-Unsubscribe", value: this.unsubscribe_link);
                }
                message.From = new MailAddress(address: this.login, displayName: this.from_name, displayNameEncoding: Encoding.UTF8);
                foreach (String addr in to)
                {
                    message.To.Add(item: new MailAddress(address: addr));
                }
                message.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                message.Subject = subject;
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                message.Body = body;
                await smtp_client.SendMailAsync(message: message).ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Метод работает нормально, и как видно message.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
Но в итоге я получаю вот такую частичную абракадабру в заголовке (в теле всё нормально):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Любой 19-й символ в заголовке отображается вот так.